# Why does this code give the error 'Timed Out' on codingbat?

Tags: python, loops

**Scenario:** We want to make a package of 'goal' kilos of chocolate. We have small bars (1 kilo each) and big bars (5 kilos each). Return the number of small bars to use, assuming we always use big bars before small bars. Return -1 if it can't be done.

Is there some case which causes it to run in an infinite loop?

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  while goal >= 5 and big > 0:
    goal -= 5
    big -= 1
  if small >= goal:
    return goal
  return -1
```

Comment: Do you think your code works ? What values do you give to `small` and `big` ?

Comment: It works in most cases that I have tried, but the website (codingbat.com) tries out multiple cases. One of these must've caused an infinite loop I guess and I can't figure what it could be. Sorry, I'm new.

Comment: What values do you give to small and big ? Can you give me the link of the exercice ?

Comment: sure! https://codingbat.com/prob/p190859

Comment: the values I put in for the parameters were ints such as make_chocolate(4, 9, 18)

Comment: Your code is functionally correct, but there is a test case with a huge goal and your code, which repeatedly subtracts 5 from it takes too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use more arithmetic to solve that

```py
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    big_that_can_fit = goal // 5
    big_that_we_use = min(big_that_can_fit, big)
    goal -= big_that_we_use * 5
    if small >= goal:
        return goal
    return -1
```

*That passes https://codingbat.com/prob/p190859 test*

Comment: Just wondering so that I don't make the same mistake again: Do you perhaps know why it gave the error?

Comment: @EdwardRoy "Timed Out" jsut means that your code takes too long. But your code was very good, just the website seems very strict so it needed another way; but your code was nice

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, I think this logic should work:

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    #Case when goal can't be made using the given quantity of chocolates (small or big)        
    if (small + big *5 ) < goal:
        return -1
    #Case when the big bars will suffice, and the remaining goal may or may not require the smaller units
    elif ((big * 5) > goal):
        return goal % 5
    #Number of small bars used otherwise
    else:
        return goal - big *5
```

Comment: The code didn't miss at all the else, because there is a `return` in the `if` so "else" or not doesn't matter

Comment: @azro Apologies, this was stupid. I'll remove the edit.